# Tool to Shrink/Expand Windows Server 2003 Partitions In RAID Array

Tags: windows-server-2003, partition

I have an old Windows Server 2003 box that I manage that is used for file storage. It is a physical server (HP AiO Storage Server), not virtualized.

The boot partition on it is only 20gb in size, which was probably fine 4-5 years ago when it was deployed, but now it is nearly completely filled up just with Windows updates.

I need to expand that partition and shrink another one (as there isn't currently any space to expand into).

Potentially complicating this is the fact that the HDDs are setup in a RAID array using a hardware RAID controller.

What is the best way to go about resizing these partitions? Free is preferable but not necessarily required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention it is an HP server, have you tried the HP Array Config Utility?

Comment: I've not but my understanding of the HP ACU is that it is for changing the Logical Arrays not the Windows Partitions...is it able to do both?

Comment: So it wouldn't be able to touch the Windows partitions but if you were able to build another logical drive then maybe you would have enough breathing room to move things around?

Comment: This is a system with direct attached storage and all of it was allocated at deployment back when it was originally setup (far before I arrived at this company). Not a bad idea but that work for me. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah got it.  Just brainstorming, I was hoping it would spark an idea for you :)  It isn't RAID 1 is it?

Comment: RAID 5...I may just have to completely backup all of the data, redeploy the server, and then move it back. However, I'm hoping to avoid that for obvious reasons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you know this, but...

Back everything up first. Back it up to multiple locations if possible. What you are doing is risky, and the proper precautions need to be taken first.

I'm assuming you want to resize by taking away space from one partition that already has data on it. This usually ends poorly, and honestly I would recomend backing everything up and rebuilding the server from scratch. Just because you have free disk space does not mean you can just resize it.

That being said, I would use something like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parted_Magic. But be prepared to have this thing offline for a while if something goes wrong.

Comment: I have backups of everything as part of SOP but it would be much simpler to resize the partitions if possible vs. having to restore 5tb of data. Appreciate the heads up though.